# CFML / Fusebox 5.5: Parse Engine Fails (sometimes) to close CFIF tags

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, fusebox

This is Fusebox 5.5.1 application. For some reason, though I've been using Fusebox for years, I'm facing a new issue recently.

The parsing engine seems to want to occasionally (and parsing the same file may make it work, and then working parsed files will fail) generate the following error:

> Context validation error for the cfcatch tag
> The tag must be nested inside a CFTRY tag.

Reviewing the parsed files by fusebox - good ones vs. bad ones, the bad versions are missing the closing /CFIF tags for some reason.

Line by line comparison, it's just missing all the lines where it should have just the closing CFIF tag, leaving 100s of open CFIF tags in the parsed file (it's not just one tag, it's all of them) - which makes the failure statement true.

So, has anyone else had this problem (with this old framework) and how was it solved.

The only thing I can think of so far, is about 3 months ago the CF server was updated both to a newest CF Version at that time and and to  faster machine. I wonder if this is an issue where the parser is running so fast (I know, grasping at straws) that it's not flusing a variable, and then that variable is set to never close the CFIF statement.

Any thoughts are appreaciated.

I've tried rerunning the parse (parsing all), I've tried running it in production and dev, and I've tried to overwrite individual files.

Comment: We had this in the past. There is a concurrency issue in the Fusebox "compiler" which can cause this to happen if more than one request hits it at the same time. We needed to make sure a server was taken offline, and that we did the recompilation in a controlled fashion, and for the entire app, and then put the server back online again. We did not get to the bottom of the precise cause from memory (this is going back a decade now, so my recollection is rusty).

Comment: If I could figure out in the code where to put one, I would place a delay in the process to ensure this wouldn't happen (just a java count for a second). That's where I'm at too! Your answer is very helpful to me (thank you!), it confirms my thoughts, now just need to understand the fb code where to put a delay in (or isolate somehow).

Comment: What was the previous version of the CF server? We saw a lot of discrepancies when upgrading across versions where like CF 9 allowed a syntax that wasn't allowed by a newer version. Have you tried running `cfcompile` across the whole codebase? Might find any legit syntax issues that could be tripping up the legacy code on the current version of CF.

Comment: Good thoughts Adrian - on migration we ran syntax checkers and fixed them. There were still a couple undocumented misses (like the date formatting becomming case sensititve) and we also updated the Fusebox vars that the new CF version now utilized.

I have now put code everywhere that Fusebox writes CFIF statements, so when it goes through it's temper tatrum again, I'll be able to better identify which CFIF line is breaking, and I should be able to fix that! :-) Will even likely post a new Fusebox archive to Github or somewhere if I can stabalize it for anyone else still running Fusebox. :-)

Comment: @FelixRutger I think yer overcomplicating it. The parsed files only get generated _once_, when there's been an update. Take the server offline, blow them all away, regenerate them all again (from memory there's a FB script to do this?), and then put the server back online. The issue only occurs when you do an update when yer online. Do this whenever you need to update. Done.